# Adwords with Landing Page then Branch Link to appstore

Tags: branch.io

I'm marketing my app on Google Adwords and my setup is like this:

1- Display network ads
2- Ads take the user to an instapage landing page that has CTA for download
3- Download button takes user to App Store/play store

My question:

Is it possible to link Branch to Instapage and how? - meaning I want to know which ad brings the conversion = as per my setup now if I have more than one ad I wont know which one got me the download.

Note: I'm paying for clicks on CPI

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the correct setup:

Branch Ads Link > Redirects to LP > CTA Redirects to Branch Normal Link > App Store

Would this track which keywords & ads from Google brought the conversion?

Comment: I believe Google would not approve the ad that redirects to an Instapage instead of a website. Assuming that Google approves the ad, if you have Branch configured correctly with your ad, it should ideally attribute the install to the particular ad. Documentation for the Display network setup are available [here](https://branchmetrics.github.io/docs/pages/deep-linked-ads/google-xplatform-display-ads/#setup)

Comment: For your question about the flow:
You can also use the flow as below:

Google Display Network ad with Branch link > redirects to your website > Use a Branch Journey on your website (documentation [here](https://branchmetrics.github.io/docs/pages/web/integrate) ). Make sure to set the parameter `make_new_link:false` > The journey CTA will lead to open or install. This will attribute the install/open to the ad.